# Two of my four links on my contact div does not work

Tags: html, css

On my contact gif I have used the social media symbols as a link to my social media sites, however, the Twitter and the GitHub link is not working and I cannot figure out why. The Facebook and the CodePen link does work. Also is there a better way correctly line and organize the Here is the links so that they can stay more consistent? site if you want to take a look for yourself [misaelalopez.com](http://misaelalopez.com). Thank you for your help!

```css
#contact 
{
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2wI0PCtgivjkGQruaV-_2JYgbuD-yNFkRLN_DGAPXHxFq5gac-lnc5IheHflI6V_Z9AtgJjyfF-LBGa4tt_W6XB2Xs26xEyAH46S7kJlgiyHeIbi-ZM62zJuHcjJuZNnhO9lMGt6jw);
  height: 250px;
  padding: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  
}

#contact h1  
{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact h2 
{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook
{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.twitter
{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.instagram
{
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.gitHub
{
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.codePen
{
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="contact">
    <div class="Content">
        <div class="facebook">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/misael.a.lopez"><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-transparent-12.png"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="twitter">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/cables25"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/piktochartv2-dev/v2/uploads/a8f46883-78d7-4dfc-b0b3-be090e70e2b3/27c835d6dd2cbb4b696abd3e7ac9c0370bbedefe_original.png"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="instagram">
          <a target= "_blank" href= "https://www.instagram.com/misael2590/?hl=en"><img src= "http://bbcpersian7.com/images/instagram-clipart-png-transparent-background-3.jpg" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="gitHub">
          <a target= "_blank" href="https://github.com/Misael2590"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-256.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="codePen">
          <a target= "_blank" href="https://codepen.io/misael25900/"><img src= "http://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Large.png" alt="CodePen"></a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h1>Reach out to me!</h1>
        <h2>Email me at Misael25900@gmail.com</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links ' don't work ' because you arrange the `divs` in a wrong way. They overlap each other. So the codepen div is overlapping the twitter,instagram,github links. Because it's positioned on top of them > you set `left:200px`  which moves the codepen div 200px from left but because it doesn't have `floaT:left` like the others, it has by default width:100% , where 100% is the width of the entire `#contact .content`

If you set float:left to the divs, this is not the way to arrange them. You need to set them a width. Having 5 divs, that's 100%/5 = 20% . And because you want some margins between them ( spaces ) , you can use `calc()` as shown below.

Also that `padding:300px` on `#contact` is a very bad idea. I don't know what you were trying to achieve with that. Anyway, i changed that also

( Changed a bit your html also because using `float` gets the elements out of their default float in the document )

All CSS styles are at the top of the code, in HTML i added a `.footer-content` div wrapping around the footer text

```css
#contact .Content  {
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#contact .Content > div {
  float: left;
  width: calc(20% - 15px);
  margin: 0 7.5px;
}

.footer-content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}

#contact {
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2wI0PCtgivjkGQruaV-_2JYgbuD-yNFkRLN_DGAPXHxFq5gac-lnc5IheHflI6V_Z9AtgJjyfF-LBGa4tt_W6XB2Xs26xEyAH46S7kJlgiyHeIbi-ZM62zJuHcjJuZNnhO9lMGt6jw);
  height: 250px;
  padding:300px 30px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
}

#contact h1 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact h2 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="contact">
  <div class="Content">
    <div class="facebook">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/misael.a.lopez"><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-transparent-12.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="twitter">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/cables25"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/piktochartv2-dev/v2/uploads/a8f46883-78d7-4dfc-b0b3-be090e70e2b3/27c835d6dd2cbb4b696abd3e7ac9c0370bbedefe_original.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="instagram">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/misael2590/?hl=en"><img src="http://bbcpersian7.com/images/instagram-clipart-png-transparent-background-3.jpg" alt="Instagram"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="gitHub">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Misael2590"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-256.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="codePen">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/misael25900/"><img src="http://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Large.png" alt="CodePen"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-content">


    <h1>Reach out to me!</h1>
    <h2>Email me at Misael25900@gmail.com</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work! I especially appreciate the explanation so I can learn. The reason why I had to add the padding was because for some reason any less would cut off the image from the bottom. I used your change (which I believe was the 30px following it), but I do not understand what the change does or why it is needed. Since I am still learning, I do not know much about Ajax and Bootstrap so I was hoping you can quickly explain what the script does. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```css
#contact 
{
  background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2wI0PCtgivjkGQruaV-_2JYgbuD-yNFkRLN_DGAPXHxFq5gac-lnc5IheHflI6V_Z9AtgJjyfF-LBGa4tt_W6XB2Xs26xEyAH46S7kJlgiyHeIbi-ZM62zJuHcjJuZNnhO9lMGt6jw);
  height: 250px;
  padding: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  
}

#contact h1  
{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact h2 
{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.facebook
{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.twitter
{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.instagram
{
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.gitHub
{
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.codePen
{
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
    <div class="Content">
        <div class="facebook">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com/misael.a.lopez"><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-transparent-12.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="twitter">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/cables25"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/piktochartv2-dev/v2/uploads/a8f46883-78d7-4dfc-b0b3-be090e70e2b3/27c835d6dd2cbb4b696abd3e7ac9c0370bbedefe_original.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="instagram">
          <a target= "_blank" href= "https://www.instagram.com/misael2590/?hl=en"><img src= "http://bbcpersian7.com/images/instagram-clipart-png-transparent-background-3.jpg" alt="Instagram" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="gitHub">
          <a target= "_blank" href="https://github.com/Misael2590"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-256.png" alt="GitHub" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="codePen">
          <a target= "_blank" href="https://codepen.io/misael25900/"><img src= "http://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Large.png" alt="CodePen" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <h1>Reach out to me!</h1>
        <h2>Email me at Misael25900@gmail.com</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```